# Java timezone what transitions mean?

Tags: java, timezone

I live in Venezuela in the last 10 years we faced 2 GMT changes.

This code was run in Java 7 update 76

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Caracas"));
```

Which prints

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Caracas",offset=-16200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=5,lastRule=null]
```

And this with the latest JDK Java 8 Update 121 of course in the end of the 2016 we have the latest change.

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Caracas",offset=-14400000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]
```

I was wonder what transitions means the documentation says something like.

**No daylight saving time transition schedule can be specified with a custom time zone ID**

But in Venezuela not day saving are made I wonder what transitions means for this particular case does mean like the total of gmt change in history or so?

Comment: In general terms, we use the word "transition" to describe when the local "wall-time" has a discontinuity.  It doesn't matter if the discontinuity moves the time forward or backward, or if it was due to daylight saving time, or a change in standard time.  It is simply the point at which some action is taken to modify the local clock.  You will find this terminology in time-keeping, across all technology platforms and outside of technology as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ZoneInfo` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/util/calendar/ZoneInfo.java) has this comment on the `transitions` field:

> This array describes transitions of GMT offsets of this time zone, including both raw offset changes and daylight saving time changes. A long integer consists of four bit fields.

Although Venezuela doesn't have DST, it did have some changes in its offset from GMT. Using the Linux command `zdump -v America/Caracas`, you get the following output:

```
America/Caracas  -9223372036854775808 = NULL
America/Caracas  -9223372036854689408 = NULL
America/Caracas  Wed Jan  1 04:27:43 1890 UT = Tue Dec 31 23:59:59 1889 LMT isdst=0 gmtoff=-16064
America/Caracas  Wed Jan  1 04:27:44 1890 UT = Wed Jan  1 00:00:04 1890 CMT isdst=0 gmtoff=-16060
America/Caracas  Mon Feb 12 04:27:39 1912 UT = Sun Feb 11 23:59:59 1912 CMT isdst=0 gmtoff=-16060
America/Caracas  Mon Feb 12 04:27:40 1912 UT = Sun Feb 11 23:57:40 1912 VET isdst=0 gmtoff=-16200
America/Caracas  Fri Jan  1 04:29:59 1965 UT = Thu Dec 31 23:59:59 1964 VET isdst=0 gmtoff=-16200
America/Caracas  Fri Jan  1 04:30:00 1965 UT = Fri Jan  1 00:30:00 1965 VET isdst=0 gmtoff=-14400
America/Caracas  Sun Dec  9 06:59:59 2007 UT = Sun Dec  9 02:59:59 2007 VET isdst=0 gmtoff=-14400
America/Caracas  Sun Dec  9 07:00:00 2007 UT = Sun Dec  9 02:30:00 2007 VET isdst=0 gmtoff=-16200
America/Caracas  Sun May  1 06:59:59 2016 UT = Sun May  1 02:29:59 2016 VET isdst=0 gmtoff=-16200
America/Caracas  Sun May  1 07:00:00 2016 UT = Sun May  1 03:00:00 2016 VET isdst=0 gmtoff=-14400
America/Caracas  9223372036854689407 = NULL
America/Caracas  9223372036854775807 = NULL
```

Watch the `gmtoff` column on the right. Each pair of lines represents one transition. You can see there were more transitions, more than 10 years ago.

Java does this a little differently, actually. It only records transitions since 1900, so the 1890 offset is not included. But it adds one dummy transition in the future. You can see the actual transitions with the following code (Java 8):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class SimpleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Caracas");

        Field f = null;
        try {
            f = tz.getClass().getDeclaredField("transitions");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            long[] transitions = (long[]) f.get(tz);
            f = tz.getClass().getDeclaredField("offsets");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            int[] offsets = (int[]) f.get(tz);

            for ( long transition : transitions ) {
                Instant transitionInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(transition >> 12);
                int offset = offsets[(int)transition & 0xF];
                System.out.println( transitionInstant + " : " + offset);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1900-01-01T00:00:00Z : -16060000
1912-02-12T04:27:40Z : -16200000
1965-01-01T04:30:00Z : -14400000
2007-12-09T07:00:00Z : -16200000
2016-05-01T07:00:00Z : -14400000
2037-01-01T04:00:00Z : -14400000
```

Comment: great but what this mean my friend. America/Caracas  Sun Dec  9 06:59:59 2007 UT = Sun Dec  9 02:59:59 2007 VET isdst=0 gmtoff=-14400
America/Caracas  Sun Dec  9 07:00:00 2007 UT = Sun Dec  9 02:30:00 2007 VET isdst=0 gmtoff=-16200 just one second?

Comment: @chiperortiz In the zdump output, each pair of lines represents a transition - the offset *before* and the offset *after*, so that's the difference of the second. Java does it a little differently. I only included the zdump output to show you that there were more transitions in the past.

Answer (score 1):

**Transitions** is an Array  and you get only the lenght of it (in this case 6)

I quote:

> This array describes transitions of GMT offsets of this time zone,
>   including both raw offset changes and daylight saving time changes. A
>   long integer consists of four bit fields. The most significant 52-bit
>   field represents transition time in milliseconds from Gregorian
>   January 1 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. The next 4-bit field is reserved and
>   must be 0. The next 4-bit field is an index value to offsets[] for the
>   amount of daylight saving at the transition. If this value is zero, it
>   means that no daylight saving, not the index value zero. The least
>   significant 4-bit field is an index value to offsets[] for total GMT
>   offset at the transition. If this time zone doesn't observe daylight
>   saving time and has never changed any GMT offsets in the past, this
>   value is null.

and here the [quelle](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/util/calendar/ZoneInfo.java)